# (Android)How can I get RGB ByteBuffer from png/jpg Image in assets directly?

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-image, android-assets

I've tried several methods to get correct bytebuffer from 192 * 144 image, containing rgb data for every pixels.
Eventually, I was able to use the double for statement to get the value, but still curious.

Here is my codes.

```
 fun getInputImage(): ByteBuffer {
    val fileInputStream = applicationContext.assets.open("input/onep_2.png")
    val image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream)

    val input = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(192 * 144 * 3)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())

    for (j in 0 until image.height) {
        for (i in 0 until image.width) {
            val color = image.getPixel(i, j)
            val r = Color.red(color)
            val g = Color.green(color)
            val b = Color.blue(color)
            input.put(r.toByte())
            input.put(g.toByte())
            input.put(b.toByte())
        }
    }
    image.recycle()
    return input
}

fun getInputImage2(): ByteBuffer {
    val inputStream = applicationContext.assets.open("input/onep_2.png")
    val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val bytes = ByteArray(110592)
    while (true) {
        val br = inputStream.read(bytes)
        if (br == -1) break
        bos.write(bytes, 0, br)
    }
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bos.toByteArray())
}

fun getInputImage3(): ByteBuffer {
    val inputStream = applicationContext.assets.open("input/onep_2.png")
    val image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
    val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos)
    val bytes = bos.toByteArray()
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)
}

fun getInputImage4(): ByteBuffer {
    val stream = applicationContext.assets.open("input/onep_2.png")
    val fileBytes = ByteArray(stream.available())
    stream.read(fileBytes)
    stream.close()
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(fileBytes)
}
```

The correct ByteBuffer was obtained only from the first function,
and the ByteBuffer size of all the functions below was much smaller than I thought.

My guess is that the bits of png/jpg are stored differently from the pixel information of bitmap, so the desired results do not seem to come out.
But I'm not sure if this guess is right, so I'm asking.

Also in 'getInputImage3()', I got the smallest size of ByteBuffer.
Even though the quality was set to 100, did the compression function produce this result?

Finally, how do I get the same result as the first function without going through the for statement?

I apologize if my English is not good enough to read.
And thank you in advance to the person who will answer.

Comment: `stream.read(fileBytes)` Dont expect that all bytes wull be read with one call. Use a loop and int nread = stream.read(fileBytes) to check.

Comment: You are not telling us that you wanna place the bytes of a file in a byte buffer. But that is what your code does. And you developed four different functions to do so. Why didnt you tell at the start of your post?

Comment: About the third function. You make a bitmap from a file and then compress a bitmap to a new file. Mostly the files will differ much in size. But do it ten times and see that file size reaches a value.

Comment: I thought I clearly stated my purpose in the title, but I guess my English was not good enough.

Comment: And I realized a little late that putting the png file in the byte buffer as it is can't have rgb data haha.

Comment: Thx for ur comment about what I didn't know. I'll never repeat making this mistake again :)

Answer (score 1):

png is a compressed bitmap file, and when it is put in the byte buffer as it is, rgb data cannot come out..

I was stupid...